# Error:The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is connecting

Tags: entity-framework, iis, model-view-controller

I have MVC-Api (Entity framework) where i'm recently started to get this kind of errors. (Not all the time)

```
System.Data.EntityException: The underlying provider failed on Open. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is connecting.

System.Data.EntityException: The underlying provider failed on Open. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is open.

//web.config
<add name="Entities" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"  connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.Model.csdl|res://*/Models.Model.ssdl|res://*/Models.Model.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=localhost ;Initial Catalog=MyDB;Integrated Security=SSPI;Application Name=Api;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;&quot;" />
//Run on IIS as local system.
```

From Global.asax the connection is registered LifestylePerWebRequest mode.

```
//registered
public static void RegDbContext()
{
  Container.Register(Component.For<Entities>().LifestylePerWebRequest());
}
//Resolved
public static T Resolve<T>()
{
  return Container.Resolve<T>();
}


//In the code.
var Entities = IoCHelper.Resolve<Entities>();
//code
var metaData = (from user in Entities.Users where user.Id == id)
```

Anybody that can give me some help? (Ps cant reproduce it localhost only on production enviorment)

Update: it always happends in  ActionFilterAttribute.

cache

Thanks!

Comment: this seems to be related to your DbContext constructor. Have you established a connection before calling the object with IoC? What does your connection string look like, is the constructor called anywhere in the code?

Comment: RegDbContext is called from Global.asax. 
var Entities = IoCHelper.Resolve<Entities>();
//code is called  inside attribute
var metaData = (from user in Entities.Users where user.Id == id)